# Rasbperry Pi 3 does not start after first boot

Tags: raspbian

After the first boot, after decompressing the image with [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), it runs perfectly.

But after shutting it down (via GUI button) the second time does not boot anymore. However the keyboard and green led do respond as seen in the last seconds of the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EgnNvKsq9k

I decompress the operative system ([04-mar-2021 relase](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-32-bit)) on the microSD with Balena Etcher again and the RPi runs again. However, if I turn it off it dies again.

Every time I shut it down (even via CLI with `sudo halt` or `sudo reboot`) I have to decompress the operative system image again.

Also I tried to press `1,2,3,4` on the keyboard to check if I can make the video to appear, but nothing happens.

What could it be wrong?

Comment: This is the MicroSD I'm using: https://telegra.ph/file/1cefd953d65f4b3ca9a3f.jpg

Comment: What are you doing between first boot and restart?

Comment: Nothing at all, actually. I tried filling and not filling the first configuration window that appears at the first boot. Always happens that the second boot does not start at all.

Comment: Did you check the file using the SHA checksum?  I would also just try the lite version.  I've known the 3B+ be very very picky over power and now swapped all to the official supply.